# My django modelform not showing any inputfields

Tags: django, django-forms

Currently i'm following a tutorial about django. But now im stuck in the process of creating forms in django. 
I watched a lot of tutorials and i have read the django docs, but i couldn't fix my problem so far.

i try to create a form from a model from my database

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
  STATUS = (
      ('Pending', 'Pending'),
      ('Out of Delivery', 'Out of Delivery'),
      ('Delivered', 'Delivered')
  )
  customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from .forms import OrderForm

def create_order(request):
   form = OrderForm()
   context = {
      'form': form
   }
   return render(request, 'accounts/create_order.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *


class OrderForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Order
      fields = '__all__'
```

create_order.html

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html'%}
{% block content%}
<form action="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token%}
  {{form.as_p}}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is, that the create_order.html shows me the labels of my form but not the input fields and i don't know why. 
i add a picture of my browser, so you an see what i mean. 
i would appreciate if anybody could help me with my problem

[image: django Browser image]

Comment: Do check what the HTML source shows; perhaps something is going that prevents displaying the fields, even if they are there.

Comment: If possible, you may also want to mention (and optionally link to) the tutorial you are following. And indicate the Django version you are using, to be complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments and i got the solution:

i use for my frontend the materialize framework. I don't know why but by default materialize set the display attribute from a select to none. 
So i made my own custome css file and set the display attribute from the select to block and it worked!

perhaps the solution can help someone else, too.

Comment: Materialize uses display:none on selects, because it uses a dynamically created text input and dropdown. (Selects also need to be initialized with JS). Checkboxes and radio buttons are set to opacity:0 because again, Materialize uses it's own elements in their place. All other inputs - text, email, textarea, submit etc - are NOT set to display:none, if you are seeing this in your stylesshet then the conflict is from another CSS file in your project.